# Why the mountain pass point cannot be a relative minimizer?

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The finite-dimensional mountain pass theorem (MPT), by Courant, states that if $F \in C^1(\mathbf R^n, \mathbf R)$ has two distinct strict relative minima $x_1$ and $x_2$, then $F$ has a third critical point $x_3$ distinct from $x_1$ and $x_2$, characterized by
$$F(x_3) =  \inf_{\Sigma \in \Gamma} \max_{x \in \Sigma} F(x)$$
where $\Gamma$ is the set of `curves' connecting $x_1$ and $x_2$.
Why the fact that $x_3$ is different from $x_1$ and $x_2$ is quite clear, I wonder why $x_3$ cannot be a relative minimizer.

I have checked proofs from several references and it seems that these proofs of this part are not clear enough. In fact, how to rule out the following scenario: $F$ is flat everywhere in part of the minimizing curve containing/around $x_3$, namely $x_3$ is not isolated.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are relative minima, neighboring points must be *higher* than each.  Thus there exists a curve $\Gamma$ that is *increasing* for nearby points to $x_1$ and *increasing* for nearby points to $x_2$.  For a joining curve, then, there *MUST* be a "top of the curve" point, where $\Gamma$ goes from *increasing* from $x_1$ and *decreasing* to $x_2$.  Thus there exists a point (which we label $x_3$) at the top.

QED.

True, there may be local minima along $\Gamma$, but the theorem just concerns the existence of the "peak" at $x_3$.

Clear?

Comment: What I understood is that you just show that $F(x_3)>\max\{F(x_1), F(x_2)\}$. (In fact, $F$ reaches its maximum value along the curve $\Gamma$ at the point $x_3$, as you pointed out.) But I still have trouble understanding why $x_3$ cannot be a relative minimum. The picture I have in mind is sort of a trapezoid. After increasing a bit, the function $F$ goes horizontally, then decreases toward $x_2$. So any point in that horizontal part can be $x_3$?

Comment: Think about it:  What is the *maximum* of all points on $\Gamma$?  Whatever it is, let's call it $x_3$.

Comment: I think now I got the point. 

The theorem only says that there is some point $x_3$ which is not a relative minima although along the minimizing curve $\Sigma$, there could be infinite many critical points that could not be a relative minima. For example, in the picture of a trapezoid, we could think that $x_3$ is one of the top two vertices. (I was thinking in the following direction: any point $x_3$ characterized by $F(x_3) =  \inf_{\Sigma \in \Gamma} \max_{x \in \Sigma} F(x)$.., which is not quite correct because there is some, not any.)

Anyway, thanks for helping me.